# Why does Rust expect double borrow (`&&'a mut T`)

Tags: types, rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

My code looks like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c8ea64026f632a10dc076c1c909fc02f):

```
pub enum Cache<'a, T> {
    Pending(&'a dyn FnOnce() -> T),
    Cached(T),
}

impl<'a, T> Cache<'a, T> {
    pub fn get(&self) -> &mut T {
        // This caches and borrows the T
    }
}

impl<'a, T> PartialEq for Cache<'a, T>
    where &'a mut T: PartialEq {

    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.get().eq(other.get())
    }
}
```

But implementing `Eq` fails with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
--> src/lib.rs:20:23
|
20 |         self.get().eq(other.get())
|                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected mutable reference, found type parameter
|
= note: expected type `&&'a mut T`
               found type `&mut T`
```

I think I'm conceptually misunderstanding something.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the `T` objects themselves, or the references returned by `.get()`?

Comment: @Frxstrem Functionally, I want the T objects to be the same.

Comment: `&'a dyn FnOnce() -> T` looks like a questionable type, since you can't ever call the function. (You need to own an `FnOnce` to be able to call it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can understand why Rust is expecting an `&&mut T` by looking at the definition of the `eq()` method in the `PartialEq` trait:

```
fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool;
```

The types of the parameters to this method are `&Self` and `&Rhs`; since `Rhs` defaults to `Self` and you did not specify anything else in your trait bound, both arguments are expected to be of type `&Self`.

Now what is `Self` in this case?  Your trait bound is this:

```
&'a mut T: PartialEq
```

So the only `PartialEq` implementation the compiler can use is the one for the type `&'a mut T`, so this is what `Self` is; `&Self`, in turn, must be `&&'a mut T`, which is exactly what the compiler is expecting.

You probably want the trait bound for `T` instead:

```
impl<'a, T> PartialEq for Cache<'a, T>
where
    T: PartialEq,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.get() == other.get()
    }
}
```

Also note that you can simply use `==` instead of explicitly calling `eq()`. It makes getting the types right a bit easier, since the compiler will take references of the arguments implicitly – `a == b` expands to `PartialEq::eq(&a, &b)`.

Comment: I had added `&'a mut` based on a compiler hint I got when I tried `self.get().eq(other.get())`. But now I see I should have used `&other` instead (or easier, `==`).

Comment: great answer!  +1